# How to update badge text

Tags: ios, swift

Am using MIBadgeButton_Swift to add badge to my cart icon here is my code

```
badgeButton.badgeString = "\(cart.count)"
badgeButton.badgeTextColor = .whiteColor()
badgeButton.badgeEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(7, 0, -7, 34)
```

But when i add new item to cart the badge wont increment. It wont update the badge 
[Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ea5W5.gif)
After the popup the cart text wont update

**UPDATE**

```
 func showAlertForRow(tt: String) {
    let alert = SCLAlertView()
    let txt = alert.addTextField("Quantity")
    txt.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad
    txt.text = "\(1)"
    alert.addButton("Add to cart") {
        let ff: Best!
        let indexPath = self.tableView?.indexPathForSelectedRow
        ff = self.best[indexPath!.row]

        let app = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context = app.managedObjectContext

        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Cart", inManagedObjectContext: context)
        let cartt = Cart(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)

        print()
        cartt.name = ff.name!

        cartt.price = Double(ff.price!)
        cartt.rest_id = "\(ff.rest_id)"
        cartt.longg = ff.longg
        cartt.latt = ff.latt
        cartt.item_id = "\(ff.item_id)"
        cartt.quantity = Int(txt.text!)
        cartt.restName = ff.restName
        cartt.cookTime = "\(ff.cookTime)"

        var lt = String(ff.latt)
        var lg = String(ff.longg)
        var urlo = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=\(lt),\(lg)&destinations=\(LATITUDE!),\(LONGITUDE!)&mode=driving&language=pl-PLe"

        print(urlo)
        var url = NSURL(string: urlo)
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        session.dataTaskWithURL(url!) {
            (data, response, error) in
            let jsonObj = JSON(data: data!)
            let yy = jsonObj["rows"][0]["elements"][0]["distance"]["value"].int
            var converted:Int?

            if yy <= 5000{
                converted = (yy! / 1000) * 80
            }else{
                converted = (yy! / 1000) * 65
            }

            print("CONVERTED IS \(converted!)")

            if converted < 400{
                converted = 400
            }

            cartt.delivery = converted

            print("TOTALAMT\(converted)")

            }.resume()



        if let imageUrl = ff.imageString{
            cartt.imageUrl = imageUrl
        }
        //img is from the outlet

        //save
        context.insertObject(cartt)

        do{
            try context.save()
            print(cartt.longg)
            print("saved")

        }catch{
            print("could not save ahaha")
        }
        self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)

    }
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.badgeButton.badgeString = "\(self.cart.count)"
        print("IT GOT HERE")
        self.updateBadge()
    }
    let imagBu = UIImage(named: "shopping_cart_loaded.png")
    alert.showSuccess("", subTitle: "Add \(tt) to cart", circleIconImage: imagBu, closeButtonTitle: "Close")
}
```

Comment: What happens when addToCart button is tapped ? Are you sure that cart.count is not zero in badge updating method ?

Comment: No it is not zero if it leave the view and come back it will be updated

Comment: So where did you put the above mentioned code ? In which method ?

Comment: Inside viewDidLoad

Comment: You need to update (same code) when you tap the add to cart button. The viewDidLoad method will be called when the view gets loaded

Comment: Ok thank you had to call viewDidLoad() when the button is tapped

Comment: Don't call viewDidLoad directly. Create a new method and just put the code in it, and call that method from wherever you want. viewDidLoad and other view life cycle methods shouldn't be directly invoked from our own code.

Comment: It still did not work that way

Comment: Is that code is being executed (above mentioned code) when you click on add to cart button ?

Comment: Have updated the button code

Comment: Just comment `self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)` and tell me whether the badge is getting updated or not. It's not a solution, just asked for clarifying one query that I have. I think you have badgeButton in two different class. You are updating the one in your current class and calling popViewController, but the previous class still has the old badge button with old value

Comment: Thank you i already fixed it forgot to refresh the cart data from core data when the button is tapped

Comment: Unrelated but `txt.text = "\(1)"` should be `txt.text = "1"`.

Comment: Yes that is just a default value for the textfield